# why umask result differs from the permission bits

Tags: linux

I want to create a file with permission bits : 125 => --x-w-r-x .

So the umask value should be => 666-125 = 541

so when I write commands below ;

```
umask 541
touch /tmp/newfile
ls -l /tmp/newfile

the result is :  --w--w-rw-
```

Why the result is not --x-w-r-x ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Note that umask is applied as the bitwise "and"
 operation, not subtraction.

Answer (score 3):

The default starting bits for a normal file (as opposed to a directory or symbolic link) are `0666`.  Let's break that down into the component permissions:

- `0` means that no special permissions (such as `setuid` (4), `setgid` (2), or `sticky` (1)) are set
- the first `6` (or `110` in binary) means that the `user` gets `r` (the first `1`) and `w` (the second `1`) but not `x` (the `0`) by default
- the second `6` means the same thing as the first `6`, but for the `group` instead of the `user`
- the third `6` means the same thing as the first `6`, but for `others` instead of the `user`

Now you want to *change* this default to `0125`:

- `0` means as above
- the `1` (or `001` in binary) means the `user` gets only `x` but no `r` or `w`
- the `2` (or `010` in binary) means the `group` gets only `w` but no `r` or `x`
- the `5` (or `101` in binary) means `others` get `r` and `x` but no `w`

Unfortunately the only operation that `umask` allows is `binary AND NOT`.  It does not allow integer subtraction.  So since you're starting with `0666 (000 110 110 110)`, there's simply no way to use `AND NOT` in order to get any of those `0`s to turn into `1`s.

The closest you can get with `umask` is `--- -w- r--` or `0024` by masking out `110 (6)` from the `user` default, `100 (4)` from the `group` default, and `010 (2)` from the `others` default.  Then every new file you create will be

```
umask 642
touch file.txt

000 110 110 110 &~
000 110 100 010
--- --- --- ---
000 000 010 100
  0   0   2   4  --- -w- r-- file.txt
```

If you want new files to then also have `x` permissions, you will have to add them in a second step (or use something other than `touch`), for example: `chmod u+x,o+x file.txt`.

::edit::
The reason you will often see odd-valued `umask`s is because the default **directory** permissions are `0777`, so users might want to specify what happens to the `x` permissions for those.  But no matter what `x` bits you specify in your `umask`, it can't affect file permissions:

```
umask 0027
touch file.txt

000 110 110 110 &~
000 000 010 111
--- --- --- ---
000 110 100 000
  0   6   4   0  rw- r-- --- file.txt

mkdir directory

000 111 111 111 &~
000 000 010 111
--- --- --- ---
000 111 101 000
  0   7   5   0  rwx r-x --- directory/
```

So you can specify `x` masks in your `umask` for when you create a new directory, but they will have no effect on file creation.

Answer (score 1):

From the `fopen(3)` man page:

```
   Any  created files will have mode S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP
   | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH (0666), as modified by the  process's  umask  value
   (see umask(2)).
```

They must be explicitly changed after creation if you want any other bits set. `touch` does not do that.

Also, your math is wrong.

```
>>> oct(0666 & ~0125)
'0642'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,So why the mask value 026 works for files with desired bits set ?

Comment: 0642 outputs me :  '-----w-r--'

Comment: How is that any surprise, assuming you've actually read the answer?

Comment: You have said any created files have mode rw-rw-rw- (Full control) , so why the files created with default umask 022 have '-rw-r--r--' permission bits set ?

Comment: "as modified by the  process's  umask  value"

Comment: I had changed the umask value , but the result isn't and of not(umask=0642)!!how can get the 125 with umask command ?

Comment: "Any  created files will have mode S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH (0666)"